# how to add PHP Path

Tags: php, include

I am new to php and currently I am facing an issue , I have a directory in root folder of server say "MyFiles" and all db functions and code files in it.
I have another folder inside "MyFiles\Forms" in this folder I have html form code and upon button submit I am calling a php file which is located in directory "MyFiles" , when I am running app its says document not found.
below is the structure,
**www\Myfiles**

*register.php*

*login.php*

*logout.php*

***Forms***

*register_me.php*

*prompt_me.php*

In **"register_me.php"** I am calling "register.php" .

below is the code

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="./Register.php">

First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value='<?php  if(isset($_POST['FirstName'])) {echo $_post['FirstName']; }?>' >
<br><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value='<?php  if(isset($_POST['LastName'])) {echo $_post['LastName']; }?>' >
<br><br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="Password" value='<?php if(isset($_POST['Password'])) {echo $_post['Password']; }?>' >
<br><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="Email" value='<?php  if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {echo $_post['Email']; }?>' >
<br><br>
Device ID: <input type="number_format" name="DeviceID" value='<?php if(isset($_POST['DeviceID'])) {echo $_post['DeviceID']; }?>' >
<br><br>
Phone No: <input type="number_format" name="PhoneNumber" value='<?php if(isset($_POST['PhoneNumber'])) {echo $_post['PhoneNumber']; }?>' >
<br><br>
Active: <input type="number_format" name="IsDeleted" value='<?php if(isset($_POST['IsDeleted'])) {echo $_post['IsDeleted']; }?>' >
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="../register.php">
```

Comment: it says.  /MyFiles/Forms/Register.php was not found on this server.

Comment: If your `register_me.php` file is in `myFiles/Forms/` and your `register.php` is in `myFiles`, You can call `../register.php` like this.. Please make sure your Path

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<form method="post" action="/Forms/Register.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

use full url for form action :

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/MyFiles/register.php">
```

Comment: But I have uploaded these files to a folder in domian.. So I have to mention only the folder. Rest the server path I'm already attaching from. Outside